# Does anyone know how to remove "Trojan:HTML/CryptoStealBTC" from Windows 10 DELL laptop?

Tags: windows-10, networking, security, trojan

[snip of the message from windows defender system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/36AkF.png)

I have tried all ways to Quarantine, Remove the said threat from my system using Windows Security System. Still it is coming up as a threat to the system. If anyone knows how to affectively remove this threat from the system it would be of great help. I read somewhere in Reddit that it could be a False Positive and appearing on Dell Laptop only. I have been using my system very cautiously and have not downloaded anything random. I posted the same question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71328326/12233845) and someone suggested to post it in Superuser. Hope I am in the right place, now.

Does anyone know how to completely remove it from the system, so I don't see the red cross in the Windows Security System ?

Comment: See if this Microsoft Article helps.   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?Name=Trojan:HTML/CryptoStealBTC&ThreatID=2147811035     If not, you may need to reinstall Windows 10.

Comment: "If anyone knows how to affectively remove this threat from the system it would be of great help." - Use different software to attempt to identify the threat.  It also might be a false positive.  I assume you are not doing crypto mining? Sadly without more specific information, other than using different software, there isn't really a specific answer we can provide.

Comment: @Ramhound How do i be sure it's a false positive ? And yes I don't do crypto mining. I guess I mentioned it that "I have been using it cautiously", so that part is included in that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Ankita - Run different security software.  Since a filename is not provided, it's impossible for us to provide specific help, to that particular threat since that threat I have no doubt can be any number of filenames.